# convert the array to given json format

Tags: javascript, json

I have the array which I want to convert it into required json format

```
Array ( [0] => 12345@gmail.com [1] => 3321312312312@21432143214.com [2] => A@B.com [3] => abc@fd.com [4] => ABCD@gmail.com  )
```

required json format

```
[
    {id:0,text:"12345@gmail.com"},
    {id:1,text:"3321312312312@21432143214.com"},
    {id:2,text:"A@B.com"},
    {id:3,text:"abc@fd.com"},
    {id:4,text:"ABCD@gmail.com"}
]
```

I have tried as

```
var jsonObj = {};
for (var i = 0 ; i < sampleArray.length; i++) {
    jsonObj["id:" + (i+1)] ,"text:" sampleArray[i];
}
console.log(jsonObj);
```

getting error.How to convert it into required form

Comment: *required json format* - that's **not valid json** - put it in a json lint to check

Comment: `const yourNewArray = yourOriginalArray.map((item, index) => { id: index, text: item })`

Comment: A minor change to your code to get closer your *required* (but not "JSON") output:  `jsonObj["id:" + (i+1)] = "text:" + sampleArray[i];`

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: Why not use PHP to convert the Array to JSON. Please see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php One issue I see is that your Array, in PHP, is not constructed properly. See more: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array

Comment: @Twisty why is the question even tagged php?  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply map the `sampleArray`

```js
const sampleArray = ['12345@gmail.com', '3321312312312@21432143214.com','A@B.com', 'abc@fd.com', 'ABCD@gmail.com']

var jsonObj = sampleArray.map((el, index) => ({id: index + 1, text: el}))
console.log(jsonObj);
```

Answer (score 2):

For a solution you may be a little more familiar with, here is a fixed version of the loop you tried to use. For each element in the a array I created an object called `item` and stored in it the desired `id` for the index of the element in the array and `text` for the text value stored at that index, I then pushed the `item` object into an array.

```js
const sampleArray = ['12345@gmail.com', '3321312312312@21432143214.com','A@B.com', 'abc@fd.com', 'ABCD@gmail.com']

var jsonObj = [];
for (var i = 0 ; i < sampleArray.length; i++) {
  var item = {id:i,text:sampleArray[i]};
  jsonObj.push(item);
}
console.log(jsonObj);
```

Additionally, I think that strict JSON requires that an array in JSON is nested in an object though many parsers will accept it this way.
Also see @freedomn-n's comment below.

Comment: To clarify, my issue was with lack of `"` around the identifiers.   There's also the distinction between a javascript object (as this answer) and "json" (a string) - but that's just `JSON.stringify(jsonObj)`...  see "jsonObj" - makes no sense :)  it's like calling a variable `var intObj` or `var intString`.   Upvoted your answer anyway as it's *probably* what OP actually wants (same as upvoted other answer with different code, same end result)